# How to get only TTS Locale in Android

Tags: android, locale, text-to-speech

I could get Locale using below code

```
Locale.getAvailableLocales();
```

and it is getting huge locales available in the device. I am looking for Locales available only for TTS.

another option I found is cross check with below function, I am not comfortable to check for all available locale using below code.

```
mTts.isLanguageAvailable(localeLang)
```

Can any one please suggest me the best way to get only TTS locales

Answer (score 2):

There is no API for this. Additionally, supported locales are TTS engine specific, so there is no such a thing as 'TTS locales available on the device'. You can check the supported locales for the current (or default) TTS engine, but not for all engines at once. How many locales do you need to support and why is calling `isLanguageAvailable()` a problem?

Comment: Thanks Nikolay, Currently I am using isLanguageAvailable method only. I thought of using direct available options if any  instead of using isLanguageAvailable method, since for showing only ~6 TTS locales I need to compare with almost >30 locales available on the device.

Comment: Why do you compare with device locales? Does not related to languages offered by a TTS engine. Maybe compare with the current locale only?

Comment: As per my scenario I need to show up all possible locales which support TTS